# How to check if function is Lipschitz continuously differentiable?

Tags: functions, derivatives

I do have a problem with achieving convergence in Newton method (using Armijo rule) for system of algebraic non-linear equations. I suspect that my function is not continuously differentiable, however I'd like to be sure if that is so. How do I test it if my **F**( **x** ) is Lipschitz continuously differentiable?

Thanks in advance,
Regards

Comment: Are you referring to Lipschitz Continuity?

Comment: Yes, I do. In general I know what is contuinity etc. But I cannot find an example with Lipschitz continuity in any of my math handbooks.

Comment: Are you asking for a definition of Lipschitz continuity?

Comment: Yes, and how to testif my function is continous (after googling a little i know it isn't, but I need to prove it)

Comment: If your function ${\bf x}\mapsto {\bf F}({\bf x})$ is some sort of explicit expression in terms of elementary functions it is continuously differentiable wherever bona fide defined; i.e., excepted in points where $\log0$, $\sqrt{0}$ and such things occur.

Comment: Then see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two conditions are being confused here, because the second one is less known and is inconsistently named.

1. A function $f$ (either scalar or vector valued) is *Lipschitz* if there is a constant $L$ such that $\|f(x)-f(y)\|\le L\|x-y\|$ for all $x,y$. This is denoted by $f\in\mathrm{Lip}(U)$ or $f\in C^{0,1}(U)$ where $U$ is the domain of $f$.
2. A function $f$ is *Lipschitz smooth* or *Lipschitz continuously differentiable*  if there is a constant $L$ such that $\|\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y)\|\le L\|x-y\|$ for all $x,y$. This is denoted by $\nabla f\in\mathrm{Lip}(U)$ or $f\in C^{1,1}(U)$ where $U$ is the domain of $f$.

That is, the second condition is the Lipschitz continuity of first-order derivatives. 
A sufficient condition for $f\in C^{1,1}$ is that the second derivative of $f$ is bounded: see [$C^{1,1}$ regularity.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/172442/79365)